# Scrolling vertically in jspScrollable area moves content out of view

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have an area on my webpage that I have used jScrollPane on. It should scroll horizontally, and does so. The height of the elements is less than the container, and there is no vertical scrollbar that appears.

However, when I use my mousewheel to scroll down the page, if my cursor is over the scrolling pane, it will scroll all the content inside up until the bottom comes into alignment with the cursor, then scrolls the page. So the horizontally scrolling content is now almost off the page inside the overflow hidden container.

As it scrolls horizontally, the left property in the jspPane adjust properly, but it always says the top hasn't moved. Same with and of the containers on the page.

I tried setting the horizontalDragMaxWidth to 1, but that had no effect.

This is a problem in all browsers I have tested. If I don't instantiate the jScrollPane, then it scrolls horizontally fine and doesn't have the vertical scrolling problem.

What can I do to prevent this scrolling off the page?